# dotnet sonarscanner fails during Docker builds

Tags: docker, .net-core, sonarqube

I am working on implementing a solution for a sonar scanner inside a docker container for the .net core application in azure DevOps.

Currently, the sonarqube installed was on a sonarqube namespace in the AKS cluster and our dot net application is containerized in a different namespace in the same cluster. I'm struggling with the following error: **The temporary analysis directory (usually .sonarqube) doesn't exist. The "begin" step was probably not executed.** Is there any sample or working Docker file which implements this type of logic? I tried to follow the steps described in [this](https://pumpingco.de/blog/how-to-run-a-sonarcloud-scan-during-docker-builds-for-dotnet-core/) blog post but the result is the same.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jdk
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-sonarscanner
RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-reportgenerator-globaltool
RUN dotnet tool install --global coverlet.console

## Set the dotnet tools folder in the PATH env variable
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"

## Start scanner
RUN dotnet sonarscanner begin \
  /k:"my-token" \
  /o:"my-org" \
  /d:sonar.host.url="sonar-host" \
  /d:sonar.login="sonar-token" \
  /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=/coverage.opencover.xml

COPY my-project/*.csproj ./my-project/

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/my-project
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet build -c Release -o /app/build --no-restore
RUN dotnet test /p:CollectCoverage=true /p:CoverletOutputFormat=opencover /p:CoverletOutput="/coverage"

## Stop scanner
RUN dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login="sonar-token"

FROM build AS publish
WORKDIR /src/my-project
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "my-project.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue may be running `dotnet restore` *after* the `sonarscanner begin`.  If you re-arrange those steps, you should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Found this: https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarqube-is-not-showing-msbuild-analysis/44455/7

This is what did the trick for me:

> the begin, build and end stages all need to be run from the
> same directory. It looks like your build script is changing the
> directory between build and end.

Be careful with the WORKDIR statements in your Dockerfile and ensure all those 3 commands are executed within the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Worked by installing dotnet-sonarscanner locally. Use the below command in the dockerfile

```
RUN dotnet new tool-manifest --name <name>
RUN dotnet tool install --local dotnet-sonarscanner --version 5.14.0
```